# Placeholder text property

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I have a place holder text that is not fitting the UITextField.
How can I set the placeholder property to fit the text?

I'm using swift.

[image]

Comment: Make the text field longer or make the text shorter. What exactly is the question?

Comment: @matt I wanna keep the font/text and field size same as other fields. I just wanna this 'Placeholder' to resize it self so that it fits all the chars. something like 'SizetoFit'.

Comment: You can't keep the font size too big and have the text field be too small; the idea makes no sense. If you want the text to fit, _make_ it fit.

Answer (score 1):

you can change the width of the textfield or change the font size

```
let font = UIFont(name: "MyFont", size: 11)!
let attributes = [
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.lightGrayColor(), 
        NSFontAttributeName : font]

textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Type something",
        attributes:attributes)
```

where your should set the font size according the size of your element.

If you need an automatic font size change, i suggest calculate the size width of the UITextfield and found a constant proportion with the font size and set it

Comment: This answer is too broad. From where did you take size 11? How OP need to calculate size?

Comment: @Eduardo Oliveros I wanna keep the font size as its I just wanna current string to fit it self like 'SizetoFit'

Comment: @ShadowOf you should calculate the size, 11 is my example

Comment: @Mr.KLD i don't know a property like SIzetofit to placeholder text, i suggest calculate the size with the width of the UITextfield, try set differents sizes of fonts, for each sizes of elements

Comment: @Mr.KLD "I wanna keep the font size as its I just wanna current string to fit" But that is the part that makes no sense. "I want to get into these pants that are too small for me. I don't want the pants to get bigger and I don't want myself to be any smaller, I just want to fit." How can that be????

Comment: @matt What I mean is that I want the placeholder text to have the same behaviour of the UITextField how it fits the text in the box. Currently, the placeholder text is not resizing it self. Or maybe I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @Mr.KLD Okay, now I understand. — Well then, this answer is right. The placeholder text is not going to resize itself; if you want it to be smaller, you must _make_ it smaller. `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` operates on the `text`; it does not operate on the `placeholder`.